# Bash script is waiting to open second file in gedit until I close the first one

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gedit

I wrote a simple bash script to create and open two files

```
#!/bin/bash  

mynewdate="$(date '+%d-%m-%Y')"
cd /my/path/
echo "praparing files..."

pilot="pilot-mode-"${mynewdate}
echo $pilot
touch $pilot
cat pilot-mode-schema >> $pilot
gedit $pilot

cd distractions
distratcions="distractions-"${mynewdate}
echo $distratcions
touch $distratcions
cat distractions-schema >> $distratcions

gedit $distratcions
```

but when I open the first one

```
gedit $pilot
```

it opens and the second one opens only after I close the first one.

How can I change the script to open two files at once?

I was trying to look for similar answers on askubuntu and other places but with no luck

and also tried adding ; sign at the end of line, still the same.

Comment: have you tried opening them in the background ?

Comment: do you mean 'myscriptname.sh &' ? I'll try.

Comment: no, I meant ``gedit $pilot &``

Comment: great, that one worked, thanks a lot :)

Comment: It is also possible to open both files at once: Execute `gedit "../$pilot" "$distratcions"` at the end of your script. You might also want to use `nohup gedit ... &` so that the editor stays open, even after you kill the script / close the terminal.

Comment: Unrelated, but good to know: Paste your script into https://www.shellcheck.net/ to avoid common mistakes and learn a lot about bash programming.

Comment: thanks @Socowi, gedit with two arguments also works like I wanted, and when I closed the terminal - gedit window still stays open :)